# I want to select multiple column by device id with max date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to select multiple row with device id of max date but I do only get one row

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    trackinfo AS [data]
WHERE
    Time = (SELECT MAX(Time) FROM trackinfo WHERE DeviceId = 11)
```

Can someone please help me with this?

I also tried to use

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    trackinfo AS [data]
WHERE
    Time = (SELECT MAX(Time) FROM trackinfo WHERE DeviceId in (11,12))
```

but still no help. please find below image of dummy data i want to select two rows with deviceId 11 and 12

[image]

Comment: What's the datatype of `Time`? Is it `DATETIME`?

Comment: your tag conflicts... what is your dbms ? SQL Server or MySQL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DeviceId ORDER BY [Time] DESC)
    FROM trackinfo
    WHERE DeviceId IN(11, 12)
) t
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Kindly include some sample data and expected result?

Comment: have added sample data image, I want two rows to be returned 1 with deviceid 11 and one with device id 12

Comment: So you want to select the max for each `DeviceId`?

Comment: yes it worked like charm, you are maste of sql thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No need to include the `DeviceId` in your sub query .. try this...

```
SELECT *
FROM trackinfo AS [data]
WHERE DeviceId IN (11, 12) AND Time = ( SELECT MAX(Time) FROM trackinfo )
```

Comment: No I want two rows with deviceid 11 and 12, for single it's running perfectly

Comment: I see, the use `IN` .. i modified my answer.. see if it helps

Comment: I tried still it's returning one row, I think that max time also comparing time between them, thing is that both have same time upto mili second

Comment: Are you sure that both deviceid 11 and 12 have the same time stamp ?